# About Definition of an Open Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

Definition: A function $f$ is said to be an open mapping if the image of every open set in its domain is itself open.
So:
If we have $f:K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $K \subseteq D$ , $D$ is the domain of analyticity of $f$.

Then $f$ maps  $K^\circ$ to $(f(K))^\circ$ and $\partial(K)$ to $\partial f(K)$, where $\partial K $ denote the boundary of $K$?

Comment: It need not be the case that $f$ maps $\partial K$ to $\partial f(K)$. $f(\partial K)$ can have points in the interior of $f(K)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What about if $K$ is compact, does it hold?

Comment: No, suppose $K$ is the right half-disk, and $f(z) = z^3$. The part of the boundary on the imaginary axis is mapped into the interior of $f(K)$. The $f(K^\circ) \subset (f(K))^\circ$ holds of course if $f$ is an open mapping.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh. But  it is $\partial f(K)$, not $f( \partial K)$. Is it still the same?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You wrote "$f$ maps ... $\partial (K)$ to $\partial f(K)$", which I interpret as meaning $f(\partial K) \subset \partial f(K)$. That does not generally hold.

Comment: @DanielFischer They used it in the following link, in the proof of the remark after the third example, were they wrong, or I missed something?:
https://dakecht.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/open-mapping-theorem-all-the-way/

Comment: Yes, they dun goofed. It's silly, because they just before proved that for a non-constant $f$, the absolute value has no local maximum in $U$, so if the maximum of $\lvert f\rvert$ on $\overline{U}$ is attained at some point $z_0 \in U$, $f$ is constant, and hence the maximum is also attained at all boundary points. [Note: if $U$ is not required to be connected, then a global maximum of $\lvert f\rvert$ in $z_0 \in U$ still implies that $f$ is constant _on the component_ of $U$ containing $z_0$, and hence the maximum is also attained at all boundary points of that component.]

Comment: @DanielFischer That is very deep to me! But thank you Daniel for letting me know it was wrong.